# How to insert multidimensional array in php?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

Just a follow-up question from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25758659/how-to-get-values-in-an-array-with-many-arrays-in-php). By getting the values from the array, my code is this:

```
       for ($i=0; $i<count($entries);$i++)
            {
                $pcode = substr($entries[$i][0],0,-2);
                $sku = substr($entries[$i][0],2);
                $aprice = $entries[$i][1];
                $beginv = $entries[$i][2];
                $delivery = $entries[$i][3];
                $endinv = $entries[$i][4];
                $offtake = $entries[$i][5];
                $bo = $entries[$i][6];
                $shelf = $entries[$i][7];
                $gondola = $entries[$i][8];
                $chillers = $entries[$i][9];
                $mass = $entries[$i][10];
                $other = $entries[$i][11];
                $total = $entries[$i][12];

                $statement = "INSERT INTO `report_details` VALUES ('$id', '$pcode', '$sku', '$aprice', '$beginv', '$delivery', '$endinv', '0', '0', '$offtake, '0', '0', '0', '$bo', '$shelf', '$gondola', '$chillers', '$mass', '$other', '$total')";
                $result = mysqlparseradd($statement,$db);

                if($result)
                {echo "YES";}
                else
                {echo "NO";}    
            }
```

And my array is like this:

```
Array
 (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0111
            [1] => 260.00
            [2] => 23
            [3] => 34
            [4] => 3
            [5] => 54
            [6] => 1
            [7] => 2
            [8] => 4
            [9] => 5
            [10] => 12
            [11] => 23
            [12] => 46
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0214
            [1] => 22.00
            [2] => 32
            [3] => 4
            [4] => 11
            [5] => 25
            [6] => 4
            [7] => 12
            [8] => 23
            [9] => 5
            [10] => 2
            [11] => 2
            [12] => 44
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0313
            [1] => 25.00
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 52
            [4] => 12
            [5] => 45
            [6] => 12
            [7] => 5
            [8] => 6
            [9] => 7
            [10] => 12
            [11] => 3
            [12] => 33
        )

)
```

The thing with this, I always get the value of `NO` which means that it doesn't get added to the database. My question is, what is wrong with the code that I have that it doesn't get inserted into the database? I did fine when I inserted only one row of data but not having multiple rows of data.

**EDIT**

When I print my `$statement` the result is this:

```
INSERT INTO `report_details` VALUES ('JJ1234567890_140822_140824_1020001', '01', '11', '260.00', '23', '34', '3', '0', '0', '54, '0', '0', '0', '1', '2', '4', '5', '12', '23', '46')
```

Only one value of array is being added. My `mysqlparseradd` is a function that acts like the `mysqli_query`. It executes the query.

Comment: Use $mysqli->error to see whats the problem is. I dont know whats your `mysqlparseradd` do and so i cant help you.

Comment: And please print the $statement.

Comment: @PatrickB please see my question again

Comment: Please use `var_dump($db->error);` after `mysqlparseradd` and post it :)

Comment: BTW, it's much more efficient to build the values in the loop, and then submit one big, multi-row insert at the end, rather than all these one-row inserts.

Comment: @PatrickB I get `null`

Comment: @Strawberry Then how will I achieve that?

Comment: If only one gets add (I assume the first one) it propably means that the first $statement has correct data on it and the others have NULL's or something like that. You should print the $statement that doesn't get added (prints 'NO').

Comment: @unska yes it was only the first one. I always got a NO. I don't know why it doesn't loop. There should be 3 `INSERT INTO` statement because I have put it in a loop.

Comment: @user3771102 Inside the loop , something like: $values[] = "('$id',$pcode,$sku,... etc.)"; Outside the loop $statement = "INSERT... VALUES implode($values)" or something like that (I'm not much of a PHP coder)

Comment: @Strawberry it is still the same. I only get 1 statement.

Comment: Use $db->query instead yours ;)

Comment: @PatrickB there's no problem with my `mysqlparseradd` since I can insert another data into the database without any problem. Its in the same file. But in the upper part of my program. //Just so you know I tried that and I failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error.

Use this.

```
$statement = "INSERT INTO `report_details` VALUES ('$id', '$pcode', '$sku', '$aprice', '$beginv', '$delivery', '$endinv', '0', '0', '$offtake', '0', '0', '0', '$bo', '$shelf', '$gondola', '$chillers', '$mass', '$other', '$total')";
```

Comment: Oh! I see! Thank you! That was such a simple '. My mistake.

Comment: :) Mark please if finished :D

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to your current solution, using array map and a function to build up an array of values clauses and inserting them once.

```
<?php

$statement = "INSERT INTO `report_details` VALUES ".implode(',', array_map(function($entry) use ($id) {return(format_row($id, $entry));}, $entries));
$result = mysqlparseradd($statement,$db);

if($result)
{
    echo "YES";
}
else
{
    echo "NO";
}   

function format_row($id, $entry)
{
    $pcode = substr($entry[0],0,-2);
    $sku = substr($entry[0],2);
    $aprice = $entry[1];
    $beginv = $entry[2];
    $delivery = $entry[3];
    $endinv = $entry[4];
    $offtake = $entry[5];
    $bo = $entry[6];
    $shelf = $entry[7];
    $gondola = $entry[8];
    $chillers = $entry[9];
    $mass = $entry[10];
    $other = $entry[11];
    $total = $entry[12];
    return "('$id', '$pcode', '$sku', '$aprice', '$beginv', '$delivery', '$endinv', '0', '0', '$offtake', '0', '0', '0', '$bo', '$shelf', '$gondola', '$chillers', '$mass', '$other', '$total')";
}
```